# wrapfigure only single word on first line

Tags: wrapfigure

This is my first post. I have used wrapfigure many times, but in this one document I simply cannot get the first line to completely wrap. I've read countless posts here, the wrapfigure pdf, and I cannot get the first line to wrap completely, it is only ever 1-3 words.  I really do not know how to make a MWE that would have this same issue.  If anyone has any input I'd greatly appreciate it.

================================

```
A DC bias then nulls the contact potential difference (CPD) between the tip and sample to create an image of the surface potential.
\begin{wrapfigure}[20]{l}{0.40\textwidth}
  \centering
  \vspace{-1.25em}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{vacancy1}


  \caption{caption}
\end{wrapfigure}

Strontium titanate / YSZ heterointerfaces are a model material system that pairs a vacancy conductor (STO) and an ionic conductor (YSZ) that, under bias, conduct species in opposite directions resulting in distinct vacancy concentration distributions.
```

===============================

If I change the wrapfigure width, anything, I only ever get the "Strontium titanate" or "Strontium titanate/YSZ" and then it wraps immediately.

Comment: I don't understand what you want and what you get that is different from what you want. But anyway, `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]` is wrong. It should be `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]` as `\linewidth` contains the width of the inserted box, and `\textwidth` is still the original width of the total text.

Comment: wrapfigure is supposed to go at the beginning of paragraphs, not the end.  You CAN put it inside a paragraph, but only at a line break.